# Does upgrading a tank commander's equipment do anything?

Tags: valkyria-chronicles-4

When assigning equipment in the Command Room, it's possible to give Claude Wallace an upgraded rifle, grenades, and armor. This seems a bit redundant, as Tank Commanders don't leave their tanks during battle. (Tanks are upgraded separately in the R&D Facility)

Does changing my Tank Commander's equipment do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

> There are missions where Claude will be on foot as a Scout-class soldier, instead of in the tank (e.g. Chapter 3: Rangers in the Storm). In these missions, he'll have that equipment.

That said, you're always able to change the equipment on units while positioning them before a deployment, so feel free to not give him anything fancy, and just change that when it's relevant.

Comment: So equipment will only have an effect during on-foot missions outside the tank?

Comment: The rifle, grenades, and armour you mentioned in the question? Yeah. I think the accessory affects tank performance, but I can't check right now.

Comment: For those who don’t read the spoiler, you might want to make the answer "yes, but only while on-foot" or “yes, but only during certain missions”.